# Bitcoin Cash: how to check address balance / transactions?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, blockexplorer

BlockExplorer (https://blockexplorer.com) provides a way to check bitcoin balances.

What is the alternative to check for transactions in Bitcoin Cash addresses?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Bitcoin Cash block explorers are (sorted by usefulness and features):

- ✯ BlockChair: [blockchair.com/bitcoin-cash/blocks](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin-cash/blocks)
- ✯ BTC.com: [bch.btc.com](http://bch.btc.com/)
- ✯ ViaBTC: [www.viabtc.com](https://www.viabtc.com/)
- ✯ Bitcoin.com: [explorer.bitcoin.com](https://explorer.bitcoin.com)
- *✯Coin Dance: [cash.coin.dance/blocks](https://cash.coin.dance/blocks)
- ✯ BitInfoCharts: [bitinfocharts.com/bitcoin%20cash/](https://bitinfocharts.com/bitcoin%20cash/)
- ✯ BitBox: [explore.bitbox.earth](https://explore.bitbox.earth/)
- BlockDozer: [blockdozer.com](http://blockdozer.com/insight/)
- Blockexplorer: [bitcoincash.blockexplorer.com](https://bitcoincash.blockexplorer.com)
- CoinSpace: [bch.coin.space](https://bch.coin.space)
- BitPay: [bch-insight.bitpay.com](https://bch-insight.bitpay.com/)
- Yours: [insight.yours.org/insight](https://insight.yours.org/insight/)

<sub>* Shows only blocks, doesn't show transactions.</sub>

<sup>✯ The ones without star use the same [Insight](https://insight.is) UI, so that websites may not show interesting data.</sup>