# How do you push a transaction to the Bitcoin Cash Network?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-cash, blocktrail

There are plenty of APIs for pushing to the Bitcoin network, like Smartbit's:

https://www.smartbit.com.au/api

However, the only API I found for Bitcoin Cash was Blocktrail's:

https://www.blocktrail.com/api/docs/lang/nodejs#payments_overview

And they do not seem to have a basic push endpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have listed a lot of Bitcoin Cash block explorers [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/57449/38618), and most of them are Insight block explorers so I thought they should have [Insight API](https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api). I checked all of them and the ones with API are:

- Bitcoin.com: https://cashexplorer.bitcoin.com/insight-api/tx/send
- BlockDozer: https://blockdozer.com/insight-api/tx/send
- Blockexplorer: https://bitcoincash.blockexplorer.com/api/tx/send

Comment: They also have a testnet explorer! http://tbcc.blockdozer.com/insight-api/addr/<address>/utxo

Comment: @sydwell that link is failing, any update?

Answer (score 2):

All the websites listed in MCCCS' answer are no longer operational.

Instead, you can use https://rest.bitcoin.com/#/rawtransactions/sendRawTransactionSingle and paste in your raw transaction after you press the "try it" button.

Alternatively, you can use this command: `curl -X GET "https://rest.bitcoin.com/v2/rawtransactions/sendRawTransaction/{your_raw_tx_here}" -H "accept: */*"`, replacing `{your_raw_tx_here}` by your raw transaction.

### Update:

You can now use this awesome tool: https://bch.info/en/tools/broadcast to broadcast Bitcoin Cash transactions.